# Custom Routing Aspect with StaticMappableAspectInterface on TYPO3 v9 not executed

Tags: url-rewriting, routes, typo3, typo3-9.x, aspect

I have to make a custom routing aspect for my own TYPO3 extension which use params in URL coming from JSON (not in TYPO3 database) to remove cHash into URL for SEO purpose.

So I'm following the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/ExtendingRouting.html#writing-custom-aspects) and added a CustomValueMapper.php into myExtension/Classes/Routing/Aspect

Into this file the code below for testing purpose :

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MyExtension\Routing\Aspect;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\StaticMappableAspectInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;

class CustomValueMapper implements StaticMappableAspectInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function generate(string $value): ?string
    {
        DebuggerUtility::var_dump('tagadadada');
        $value = 'fr-00002032';
        return $value;
        // die($value);
        // return $value !== false ? (string)$value : null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function resolve(string $value): ?string
    {
        DebuggerUtility::var_dump('tagadadodo');
        $value = 'fr-00002032';
        return $value;
        // die($value);
        // return isset($value) ? (string)$value : null;
    }

}
```

Into ext_localconf.php I added :

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['routing']['aspects']['MyExtensionCustomValueMapper'] = \VENDOR\MyExtension\Routing\Aspect\CustomValueMapper::class;
```

If i debug into my Controller :

```
DebuggerUtility::var_dump($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['routing'], 'mapper');
```

I can see my custom aspect declared into ext_localconf.php

```
aspects => array(7 items)
  LocaleModifier => 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\LocaleModifier' (44 chars)
  PersistedAliasMapper => 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\PersistedAliasMapper' (50 chars)
  PersistedPatternMapper => 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\PersistedPatternMapper' (52 chars)
  StaticRangeMapper => 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\StaticRangeMapper' (47 chars)
  StaticValueMapper => 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\StaticValueMapper' (47 chars)
  MyExtensionCustomValueMapper => 'VENDOR\MyExtension\Routing\Aspect\CustomValueMapper' (47 chars)
```

Into the sites configuration (into config.yaml file) I added

```
...
routeEnhancers:
  MyCustomPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: myextension
    plugin: pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/', _controller: 'myController::search' }
      - { routePath: '{myParam}', _controller: 'myController::show', _arguments: {'myParam': '{myParam}'} }
    defaultController: 'myController::search'
    aspect:
      myParam:
         type: MyExtensionCustomValueMapper
```

So URL is rewritten with routePath and looks like

> http://localhost:8080/mytestpage/fr-00002032?cHash=11a51779bcff3bc03283087ea6ff9aa1

But I don't want the cHash parameter.

In fact it's like my CustomValueMapper.php file is not read. If I add a big syntax error into it, nothings happens. No error displaying, nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into the site configuration (into config.yaml file),
If you have multiple parameters sent to the controller
All parameters have to be mapped, otherwise missing parameters are "hidden" in the chash parameter.
for example :

```
routeEnhancers:
MyCustomPlugin:
type: Extbase
extension: myextension
plugin: myplugin
routes:
  - routePath: '/'
    _controller: 'myController::search'
  - routePath: '/{myParam}'
    _controller: 'myController::show'
    _arguments: 
      myParam1: 'myParam1'
      myParam2: 'myParam2'
      myParam3: 'myParam3'  
defaultController: 'myController::search'
aspect:
  myParam1:
     type: MyExtensionCustomValueMapper
  myParam2:
     type: MyExtensionCustomValueMapper
  myParam3:
     type: MyExtensionCustomValueMapper
```

It might be working ...
Best regards